# What is this JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What would the following code do?

I have used JS for years but haveno idea how this construct works?

```
(function() { /* No implementation yet */ })();
```

Knowing that there is no implementation - if there were - how would I invoke it? Would the following make an anonymous object?

```
var temp = (function() {  })();
```

Which I could use as:

```
temp.doWhateverDefined();
```

Comment: You cannot unless you returns some function (doWhateverDefined) from that function.

Comment: It's already being invoked. It's meant as a one-time-use function to create a local variable scope.

Comment: it is an anonymous function, which is called just after it's defined....

Answer (score 4):

You have an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). It is very common in JavaScript.

Comment: Thats kinda cool it's like inline code that is executed but in a function scope - but without explicitly calling any function???

Comment: @Alex.Barylski it explicitly calls the anonymous function wrapping the code. In JavaScript, you invoke a function by adding parens, `()`. This defines a function, and then immediately calls it by appending `()` to the end. Worth noting, the final `()` can be inside OR outside the wrapping parens. `(function() {}())` is just as good as `(function() {})()`

Answer (score 2):

```
(function() { /* No implementation yet */ })();
```

This is called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression or shortly IIFE. It is declared, evaluated and called immediately.

The basic idea is:

```
var x = (function() { return 5;})();
alert(x); //5
```

Comment: Or *IEFE*? I guess that works too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's being run immediately.  It's as if you said:

```
var f = function() { /* No implementation yet */ }
(f)();
```

which is the same as

```
var f = function() { /* No implementation yet */ }
f();
```

The point of it is to allow a block of code (page initialization, etc.) to use whatever variable/function names it likes, without conflicting with other Javascript code that may use the same names.  All the functions/etc. declared in that block are local, and don't harm the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

That is an anonymous function so you cannot invoke other than in the line where you create it unless you assign it to a name

```
var temp = (function() {  })();
```

This piece of code should be changed to

```
var temp = (function() {  });
```

That way you actually assign the function to the name. To invoke it just use a parentheses

```
temp()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a self-executing function. You do not invoke it, it does it automatically.

`var temp = (function() {  })();` would work if the function returns something.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a self-invoking function which is already called.

```
var temp = (function() {  })();
```

So the function has to returns a function so that temp() or temp.somethin(); could be triggered. See an example below for more information,

```
var temp = (function() { return {
    doWhateverDefined: function () {
        return 'invoked';}
      };  
    }
)();

alert(temp.doWhateverDefined()); //should alert invoked
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5ch8F/1/

Comment: Thanks all for the replies...I kinda figured it was called immediately after being defined but I appreciate the IIFE blog thats awesome :)